# Hadoop MapReduce read and write Sequence File

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to write MapReduce job which it can Read two sequence file in the Mapper. I've tried read and write a sequence file in 'main' but I don't know how to do it in Mapper. I think that I'm not really familiar with how MapReduce work. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything is correct, in the main() method you wrote something like that:

```
 FileInputFormat.addInputPath()
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath()
```

to tell Hadoop the directory where to find your two input files and where to write the results of the computation.

When the job starts, Hadoop starts reading the files it finds in the input directory and it calls the map() method of the mapper passing to it every line of the file (one at the time) as an argument. 
At the end of the computation, when the reducer emits its data, Hadoop is going to write the results in one (or more) files in the specified output directory.

So, the mapper and the reducer don't need to know anything about input/output files.

Comment: I need to read two files from the hdfs and do some processing. Can Mapper passing two line of data from two different files to map()?

Comment: If in the input directory are present two files, Hadoop will read the first file and pass every line of that file to the map() method of the mapper; then it will read the second file and pass every line of that file to the map() method.  Do you need different business logic for the two files?

Comment: If I gave two directories, the mapper will pass every line of two file sequentially, right? 

How can I make mapper method pass two lines of data from two different files at the same time?

Comment: Hadoop doesn't work like that: every instance of the mappers will receive one line at the time. If you need the lines from both files simultaneously for your business logic, you could save all the lines of the first file in the instance of the mapper and then, when it comes to the second file, use the previously saved values to compute your logic. Otherwise another solution could be merging properly the two input files (something like: the first lines of the two files, then the second lines of the files, then..) so that the mapper will read one after the other the lines of the two files.